# Android Studio: How to start TexttoSpeech after 10 seconds?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I built a App. But now I have a Problem: How can I start my TexttoSpeech after 10 seconds? I already tried to found an answer, but I didn't found. Please help my :) Thanks!

Comment: use `Handler.postDelayed(...)....`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startActivity` and write `Handler` in your code

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                     your logic after 10 seconds
                }
            }, 10000);
        }
```